# innerHTML doesn't work in IE11 and IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, innerhtml, internet-explorer-11

I use these codes for refreshing a part of my page :

```
var container = document.getElementById("mainForm:table_1");
var content = container.innerHTML;
container.innerHTML= content;
```

container.innerHTML worked well in firefox and chrome
but it doesn't work in IE8 and IE11

I've read these links :
[.InnerHTML Not working properly in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243756/innerhtml-not-working-properly-in-internet-explorer)
and
[document.getElementById().innerHTML fails with 'Unknown Error' in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096660/document-getelementbyid-innerhtml-fails-with-unknown-error-in-ie)

but my problem is that I can't change the other part of my code easily due to of dynamically generation.

1) Is there any way that I can do just with these part of my code to solve IE problem ?

2) and also i need an alternative for :

```
window.history.pushState()
```

which doesn't work in IE8 and IE9

Comment: Going to guess that `mainForm:table_1` is a `<table>` element? If so, try selecting a parent element of the table and replace the entire table.

Comment: yes you are right , it is a table . I  try to do that and how about second part of my question ? how can I add a string to url with something like pushstate that work with ie8 and ie9 too ? thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for first part of your question do this :

```
  var container = document.getElementById("mainForm:table_1").parentNode;
  var content = container.innerHTML
  container.innerHTML= content;
```

and for second part of your question as @JITHIN PV said you must use history.js

you can easily use it like this :

```
var History = window.History;
History.enabled ;
History.pushState("object or string", "object or string", "object or string");
```

Answer (score 6):

IE9 and below doesn't support pushState. For [unsupported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate) use [history API](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API). and also find some more list of [polyfills here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#html5-history-api-pushstate-replacestate-popstate).

Comment: yes you are right it doesn't work, but isn't any way to do so with native javascript or jquery ? with out using history API

Comment: @OmiD You could just stop supporting outdated/obsolete browsers. It's time we stopped pandering to people who refuse to update - especially since doing so pretty much requires manually and deliberately (and therefore, maliciously to us) disabling Windows Update.